# Why Does Record Prior Resource Not Exist in a Flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

Hello Stack Exchange Community,

We have a Record Triggered Flow in our org that is triggered when a record is created on a custom Object called "Paywall Hit". There is a text field on the "Paywall Hit" Object that  called Subscriber GUID (SubscriberGUID__c). I want to modify the trigger of this flow to not run if the previous record created on the "Paywall Hit" Object has the same value in the Subscriber GUID (SubscriberGUID__c) field.

I am trying to accomplish by creating a simple formula {$!Record__Prior.SubscriberGUID__c}. However, I am getting an error saying that the $Record__Prior resource does not exist in this flow. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Or, if there is a better way to do this? Thank you all so much!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your flow trigger is upon "record is updated"

`$Record__Prior.SubscriberGUID__c` will exist only for the flows in the update scenario.

Comment: Do you know of a way to accomplish the same goal for a flow trigger that is set to "record is created"?